# Hide class attributes in Swagger Request body using spring

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, swagger

I have a class User

```
public class User {

Integer id;
String  name;
String  department;

.... }
```

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class userResource {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@PostMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<StatusResponse> createUser(
         @RequestBody   User user) {
.....}
```

In Swagger it shows

```
{
"department": "string",
"id": 0,
"name": "string"
 }
```

I want to hide field department here.I have used @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)

But I also want to use this entity in other places and want to show the department field how that is possible?

Comment: You can create different profiles to hide/ show data accordingly.

Comment: Hi! Did you find any kind of solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class User {
     Integer id;
     String  name;

     @JsonIgnore
     String  department;
 }
```

Comment: Through this the department field will not be visible to every endpoint where I use this entity.My question is that how can I make this visible to some endpoint and not to

Comment: Good question. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem today. Here's my solution.

User Entity:

```java
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

Test Controller:

```java
@ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/test")
    @Operation(description = "SwaggerTest")
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", examples = @ExampleObject("{username: 212}")))
    @ApiResponse(content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", examples = @ExampleObject("{username: 212}")))
    public User test(@RequestBody User user){
        return user;
    }
```

And Here's the result:

[image]

Before:

[image]

By Adding @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody and @ApiResponse and setting its **content** field, you can customize what to show in swagger.

All above is based off **springdoc-openapi-ui** library.